# bootstrap typeahead only showing first character of the result

Tags: php, javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Currently, my typeahead looks like this when I am creating it in php

```
    echo '<input type="text" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source="[,';
while ( $rowresult = mysql_fetch_assoc($titlequery) ) {
      echo '{value:&quot;'.htmlspecialchars($rowresult['title']).'&quot;'."},";
}
      echo ']">';
```

It outputs like this:

```
  <input type="text" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source="[,{value:&quot;2010-11 Graf Intern&quot;},{value:&quot;2nd Year Finance Explorer, Mizani &amp; L'Oreal Technique&quot;},{value:&quot;A&amp;R Intern&quot;},{value:&quot;Account Executive&quot;},{value:&quot;Account Manager&quot;},{value:&quot;Account Service Representative&quot;},{value:&quot;Account Strategist&quot;},{value:&quot;Accountant&quot;},{value:&quot;Accounting Intern&quot;},{value:&quot;Accounting Intern/Analyst&quot;},{value:&quot;Accounts payable&quot;},{value:&quot;Acquisition Marketing Intern&quot;},{value:&quot;Acquisitions Associate&quot;},{value:&quot;Acting Manager&quot;},{value:&quot;Acting Software Manager&quot;},{value:&quot;Administrator&quot;},{value:&quot;Admissions Ambassador&quot;},]">
```

Unfortunately, it only shows the first character of each value it is able to find (value being the default for bootstrap.)

Edit:

The question revolved around formatting results, in actuality, what was happening was Javascript was trying to reference an array that didnt exist, so it took the element [0] which was the first character to it.

Comment: I dont know if it makes a different but data-minLength is not functioning correctly either.

Comment: Firstly, don't use ext/mysql (`mysql_*()` functions), use PDO or MySQLi instead. Next, you should use `htmlspecialchars(json_encode($arr))` instead of manually creating the (syntactically invalid) string like that.

Comment: Added the json_encode part, and it didnt help. P.S.Noted on the mysqli planning to move over when done developing before launch.

Comment: In case anyone hits this issue: Steps to fix:
1. Validate JSON
2. Remove "value": as it was not looking for the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this solution:

```
<?
$chars = array(":", "'", "?", '"', "/");
while ( $rowresult = mysql_fetch_assoc($titlequery) ) {
      $Str = $rowresult['title'];
      $Data[] = str_replace($vowels, "", $Str);
}
if(isset($Data)): ?>    
<input type="text" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source="[<?= implode(',', $Data) ?>]">
<?php endif; ?>
```